# Is it possible in Weblogic to create readonly JDBC datasource?

Tags: jdbc, weblogic, datasource

I am using Weblogic web server. Please let me know, how can i create a readonly JDBC datasource ,or should i handle this in my Java code ?

Comment: What do you mean by readonly JDBC datasource?

Comment: It means, that if a usert is using a connection pool created from that data source, then he should not be able to insert / update / delete..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The datasource allows you to obtain *pooled connection instances*, each pooled connection instance representing a **physical connection** to a database that remains open during use by a series of *logical connection instances*.

So, what you are allowed to do with a pooled connection instance strictly depends on the database permissions granted to the user used to create the physical connection. In other words, if you want a read only pool, use a user with restricted rights at the database level when creating your pool.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't the DBMS enforce that for you?  That is, if you connect to a database with a certain user identification the DBMS just gives read access to that database?